# Posso acessar banco de dados usando electron js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Posso acessar banco de dados com electron js, existe alguma limitação em seus uso? se sim quais?

Comment: http://knexjs.org/

Comment: Em su website não lista qualquer funcão. O que você gostaria fazer com bancos de dados em electron js?